# Zend form - reuseable decorator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a custom decorator as follow:

```
$lang = $this->CreateElement('select', 'lang')
            ->setDecorators(array(
                    array(
                        array('elementDiv' => 'HtmlTag'), 
                        array('tag' => 'div', 'class'=>'lang')
                    )
                )
            )
```

How can I reuse this decorator aliased as 'elementDiv' in my next element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$elementDiv = array('elementDiv' => 'HtmlTag');

$this->addElement('select', 'lang')
     ->setDecorators(array(
         $elementDiv,
         array('tag' => 'div', 'class'=>'lang')
     ));

$this->addElement('select', 'lang2')
     ->setDecorators(array(
         $elementDiv,
         array('tag' => 'div', 'class'=>'lang2')
     ));
```

Alternatively, you might want to create a [custom decorator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.decorators.html).